# Read variables from database to populate appsettings.json

Tags: .net, .net-core

Is it possible to, after the first connection is made, read variables from my database to populate my `appsettings.json` file, and use `reloadOnChange` to make the changes take effect without rebooting?

The first connection to the database would have to be with hardcoded strings, since it needs the initial settings to.

Would something like adding a listener to the table holding the values, and then on change updating `appsettings.json` work?

I've searched but haven't found anyone asking about this.

Comment: It should also be possible to implement a custom `IConfigurationSource` / `IConfigurationProvider` that can read configuration from the DB directly into the config system. The [implementation for the azure key vault](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/tree/dev/src/Config.AzureKeyVault) would serve as a good starting point.